# How to save attachments from IOS using Mimekit

Tags: c#, ios, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I have this code that actually works in all cases except when the image is sent by an IOS device, in that case attachments appears in blank.

I connect trough IMAP and take UIDS, then I extract information about email, save attachments and save entire email.

Everything is fine except when the sender attach documents or images by IOS, in that cases the code cant find any documents.

What can I do ?

Thanks

```
try {
    IMailFolder mailFolder = imapClient.GetFolder(Folder);
    mailFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    MimeMessage m = mailFolder.GetMessage(new UniqueId(Decimal.ToUInt32(UID)));
    //MailMessage m = imapClient.GetMessage(UID, false, false);


    Subject = m.Subject;
    From_Name = (m.Sender != null) ? m.Sender.ToString() : "";//m.Sender.DisplayName;
    From_Address = (m.From != null) ? m.From.ToString() : "";
    Cc_Address = (m.Cc != null) ? m.Cc.ToString() : "";
    Date_Sent = m.Date.DateTime;
    MessageID = m.MessageId;    
    Body = m.TextBody;
    m.WriteTo (EmailName);


    if ( Save_Attachments && Attachments_Path != "") {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Attachments_Path);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(String));

        foreach (MimeEntity attachment in m.Attachments)
        {
            if (attachment is MimePart)
            {
                MimePart part = (MimePart)attachment;
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Attachments_Path, removeIllegal(part.FileName));

                using (var stream = File.Create(path))
                {
                    part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
                }

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Path"] = path;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

             }
        }

        Attachments = dt;
    } else {
        Attachments = null;
    }

}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Subject = "";
    From_Name = "";
    From_Address = "";
    Cc_Address = "";
    Date_Sent = new DateTime();
    MessageID = "";

    Body = "";

    Attachments = null;
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using MimeMessage.Attachments, you need to use MimeMessage.BodyParts - but be aware that BodyParts *also* contains the text body of the message.

I have more information here: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm

A quick & dirty way of accomplishing what you want to do is probably something like this:

```
foreach (var attachment in m.BodyParts.Where (x => x.ContentDisposition?.FileName != null))
```

(Note: you'll need to make sure to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your C# file)